# Do Pokemon stay 'super shiny' when they evolve?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In SwSh, they added a new shiny visual effect called 'super shiny', which has square sparkles instead of stars.

Are the square sparkles kept upon evolution?

Comment: "Super shiny" is a misnomer. One isn't necessarily more common than the other, they're just obtained from different things. Star shinies are your more traditional 1/4000ish chance kind, whereas square ones are obtained from things like chaining.

Comment: fwiw, nothing in the Pokemon series indicates they _wouldn't_ be kept on evolution. Evolution never takes away special traits like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They sure do! I caught a shiny Mr. Mime, which has square sparkles. I evolved it to Mr. Rime shortly after.

I tested this, and it maintained the square sparkles when thrown into battle

[image: Shiny Mr. Rome]

Comment: Fun fact: This was my 2nd Mr. Mine that I caught, so I found it with full odds

Comment: Wow. Now that's lucky! :O

Comment: Thanks! I got a pawniard with square sparkles with only the shiny charm to increase odds, so I was really happy about finding the super shiny!

Comment: According to serebii the Square Shiny version is actually the more common one in Sword and Shield. I got a Coalossal and it has Squares as well.
https://serebii.net/swordshield/shinypokemon.shtml

Comment: @Roybin93 Well thanks for bursting my bubble :P

Comment: I'm assuming this should say Mr. Mime, not Mr. Mine.

Comment: @JMac Yes, thanks for catching that. Autocorrect has failed me once again